# Not executing sensor acquisition on C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a program for RS-422 sensor by using c#. there is no 
error in program but when i connected to the sensor for acquisition there 
is no result was shown. Program is running without error. 
I used A Chart for using rtChart and below the chart I am trying to show the chart result when I click the button. please help me to solve this my code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using rtChart;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        kayChart serialDataChart;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialDataChart = new kayChart(chart1, 60);
            serialDataChart.serieName = "serialRead";
        }

        private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort aSerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
            aSerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            aSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            aSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            aSerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialDataReceivedEventHandler);

            if(!aSerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                aSerialPort.Open();
            }
        }

        private void serialDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
            string recvData = sData.ReadLine();

            serialData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { serialData.AppendText("Received :" +recvData); });
            double data;
            bool result = Double.TryParse(recvData, out data);
            if (result)
            {
                serialDataChart.TriggeredUpdate(data);
            }

        }

        private void serialData_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialData.SelectionStart = serialData.Text.Length;
            serialData.ScrollToCaret();
        }

        private void chart1_TabStopChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add more lines as its more of code here

Comment: what sensor are you trying to connect, do you have some datasheet?

Comment: Your `aSerialPort` is going out-of-scope and probably being (partially) disposed. Declare it as a member of the class instead of a local method variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't have any datasheet as a code or soft copy. but i have initial setting  that is : 19200bps, even Parity, 7data bits, 1 stop bit

Comment: this is lessor sensor use for water level gauge... hope you will find some solution

Comment: @niksankarkee See my comment about moving the `aSerialPort` definition out of the method and into the class. I think this may solve your problem, along with setting the serial port settings correctly (you say it is 19200, but you set 9600). Also try using a Serial Port monitor application to verify the sensor is operating correctly and you have the right settings.

Comment: @RonBeyer thank you now it is working on text box. i mean data is showing on textArea but my graph is not working can you please help me on that.

Comment: I apologize, I don't have any experience with those chart controls to be of any assistance. I would recommend opening a new question with updated code and a link to the charting library you are using.

Comment: @RonBeyer Any way thank you so much for solving my problem